# ImportError at /admin/ No module named views

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I can't understand the source of this problem, anyone can help me to understand?
I checkouted from development server and all works except the admin

```
    ImportError at /admin/
No module named views
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.43.121:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.5.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named views
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/maurizio/workspace/bigfloproject',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
Server time:    Sat, 26 Apr 2014 05:07:55 -0500
```

This is the traceback:

```
    Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.43.121:8000/admin/

Django Version: 1.5.5
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django_extensions',
 'kompat',
 'customers',
 'dbeffect',
 'dbpatent',
 'spark',
 'statistics',
 'website')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
  219.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  202.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in index
  361.                             model_dict['admin_url'] = reverse('admin:%s_%s_changelist' % info, current_app=self.name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  467.                 app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in app_dict
  311.             self._populate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  274.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  297.             self._populate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  286.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  230.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  31.         result = func(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  97.             mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /admin/
Exception Value: No module named views
```

This is my url.py

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'kompat.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^kompat/', include('kompat.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    #(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
    #include url sito statico
    (r'', include('website.urls')),
    #include url dfeffectti
    (r'^dbeffect/', include('dbeffect.urls')),

    #include url kompat
    (r'^kompat/', include('kompat.urls')),

    #include url gestione utenti
    (r'^user/', include('customers.urls')),

    #include spark
    (r'^spark/', include('spark.urls')),

    #include dbpatent
    (r'^dbpatent/', include('dbpatent.urls')),
)

############# SERVING STATIC FILES IN DEVELOPMENT MODE #########


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
        }),
   )
```

This is My settings.py

```
    #from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
import os

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)



DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '..\kompatdata',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

# TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
#     "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
#     "django.core.context_processors.debug",
#     "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
#     "django.core.context_processors.media",
#     "django.core.context_processors.static",
#     "django.core.context_processors.tz",
#     "django.core.context_processors.request",
#     "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/media')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'

#directory dei file privati per sviluppo locale
PRIVATE_DIR =os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    'static',
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '5#z%#zix3()rd4@4#lb!5)r4*5xez^ees4zd5%n-_ja5qg-x3h'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

#SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.file"
#SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
#SESSION_FILE_PATH = "E:\\temp"
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True



MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'bigfloproject.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'bigfloproject.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
     os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'customers/templates/'),
     os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'dbeffects/templates/'),
     os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'kompat/templates/'),
     os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'spark/templates/'),
     os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'statistics/templates/'),
     os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'website/templates/'),
     os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'dbpatent/templates/'),
    # 'C:/Django-1.5/Django-1.5/bigfloproject/customers/templates/'
    # 'C:/Django-1.5/Django-1.5/bigfloproject/dbeffects/templates/'
    # 'C:/Django-1.5/Django-1.5/bigfloproject/kompat/templates/'
    # 'C:/Django-1.5/Django-1.5/bigfloproject/spark/templates/'
    # 'C:/Django-1.5/Django-1.5/bigfloproject/statistics/templates/'
    # 'C:/Django-1.5/Django-1.5/bigfloproject/website/templates/'
    # 'C:/Django-1.5/Django-1.5/bigfloproject/dbpatent/templates/'
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django_extensions',
    #'registration',
    'kompat',
    'customers',
    'dbeffect',
    'dbpatent',
    'spark',
    'statistics',
    'website'


)


LOGIN_URL = '/user/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/user/welcome-user/'

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "customers.User"
AUTH_USER_MODEL ="customers.User"

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 2
```

Thank's in advance

Comment: One of your urls.py has this error. Your error page may show you some more info to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: The admin module imports all the other views so the error is likely to be in one of the other applications. Comment out each set of URLs until the admin works again and then check the relevant module.